# Azure App Services with MVC 6 fails on first login only

Tags: azure

I am at a loss on how to troubleshoot this.  When I publish a web app to azure from visual studio it publishes fine.  The home page then displays in my browser fine.  I can then proceed to navigate to other pages fine.  However, when I click the login link and enter credentials I get a page error.  If I go back and click the login link again and try again it works fine.  It then continues to work until either I stop the page and start it again or nobody visits it for awhile.  Then the same thing happens, 500 error when I first try to login then works fine for awhile.  When I run from visual studio it works fine always.  It is something going on in azure after it starts.

I enabled detailed errors in azure and this is what it has:

> Module       httpPlatformHandler Notification    ExecuteRequestHandler
>   Handler      httpplatformhandler Error Code      0x00000000 Requested URL 
>   http://TestSite1113:80/Account/Login Physical Path
>   D:\home\site\wwwroot\main\Account\Login Logon Method     Anonymous
>   Logon User       Anonymous

So maybe the site is going to the incorrect location first then goes to the correct location but that doesn't make sense.

Any ideas why this would happen?

Answer (score 0):

You probably have multiple handlers defined in your web.config. Check if they are the correct ones and if the section starts with `<clear />`. This will clear the default handlers before you add your own list.